# Ms Access 2007 Blank form in Form Design for adding records

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using Ms Access 2007 and want added a Form that could be used to enter Data to an underlying table. However, when I view the Form in `Form Design`, it first shows me any existing records in the table. I use the navigation buttons at the bottom to go through all the records and right at the end, I get a blank (not populated) form so I can add a new record.

Is it possible to just create a Form that won't pre-populate existing data from the underlying table? I know I can achieve this through adding a button for that but I would like the user to open a Form that allows then to enter a new record without navigating to the last record or clicking on a button first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the forms property *DataEntry* (localized in the GUI) to: True